# Bind "media" keys on MacBook keyboard to application menu items

Tags: macos, macbook, keymap, media-keys, pandora

Currently, I am using PandoraBoy to listen to my Pandora stations.  In the preferences, it allows you to set global hotkeys to control playing, like/dislike, volume, stations, etc.

What I would like to do is allow the built-in media keys on my MacBook Pro's keyboard (F7-F12: Previous, Play/Pause, Next, Mute, Volume Up, Volume Down) to control PandoraBoy like they do iTunes.

Right now, I am using Command-F(7-12) to control it, but that requires me to hold down the "fn" and command keys

Is there a way to bind these commands to the media keys without needing to function-shift them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried FunctionFlip.  It was a [Mac OS X Hints pick of the week in 2008.](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20080915065201592)